# Are anomalies always undesirable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, chirality

In the glossary of the [AMS book on Quantum Fields and Strings](https://bookstore.ams.org/qft-1-2-s/) it is stated that

> An anomalous theory does not make sense quantum mechanically, so anomaly cancellation is a fundamental requirement of quantum theories.

However, from what I understand, a chiral anomaly means that quantum fluctuations destroy the axial symmetry of the classical theory, whose reality is an observed fact.

Are these two different kinds of anomalies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A theory with an anomalous global symmetry, like chiral symmetry, is not problematic. Global symmetries are physical, and we can break them. Breaking gauge symmetry is a problem, because gauge symmetry is just a redundancy in labelling things. A $d$-dimensional theory with an anomalous gauge symmetry is telling us that it can't exist in just $d$ dimensions, but it could exist as the boundary of a $d+1$ dimensional theory. (See [Wen, arXiv:1303.1803](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.1803.pdf))

Some more details on anomalies in global vs. gauge symmetries are in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127277/what-exactly-is-a-gauge-anomaly) by Luboš Motl.